# Python: Simple if: statement that says invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I keep on getting invalid syntax on line 2 and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
operator = input("Would you like to +, -, *, or /?:")
if (operator != "+"):
  print ("Unknown operator!")
```

I also attempted to do:

```
operator = input("Would you like to +, -, *, or /?:")
if (operator != "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"):
  print ("Unknown operator!")
```

But then it always print out "Unknown operator!"

I'm honestly very new to coding and any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @vaultah: how many times have you marked that as duplicate? 50? 100?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link me to the duplicate then, cause I couldn't find anything

Comment: the link is below the "duplicate" word :) "This question already has an answer here:"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre definitely less than 100... There's probably a way to get the exact number from the Data Explorer, but I'm not very familiar with it

Comment: at least in C noone has the idea to do: `operator != "+" || "-" || "*" || "/")`